# What is the name of the component used in the app store to show the new and noteworthy apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to use this component to develop an application and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Store is a hybrid application, using Objective-C and HTML5 to create a rich content experience.

The new and noteworthy section is created in HTML, it is not a Cocoa Touch control.

Comment: So the What We're Reading component in the Marvel strips application is also hybrid? Or is that another component? It looks the same...

Comment: Whether you do it in HTML or in Objective-C it still something you're going to have to create yourself. It's not a standard control that you can just use form a library. You'll have to build up the views, actions and layout yourself.

Comment: The Marvel app looks and feels more more like a native Objective-C Cocoa Touch app than hybrid (but I could be wrong). Their "what we're reading control is custom built.